# Setup a full node on server for frond end Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc

I am a new in bitcoin technologies. I want to setup a full node on cloud server. Also I need to use RPC of this server for front end app.That is creating bitcoin wallet and its further operations(such as send and receive). My question is

1. Is suitable to use own full node cloud server for front end wallet app(Like PHP web app) ...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but a few important points.

- Don't forget to enable `txindex`, it will allow you to query your node for all transactions.
- Don't use the RPC API on the front end. RPC is needed to make transactions, but it might allow others to withdraw your coins. Keep the RPC in the back end.
- The [HTTP REST API](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md) is suitable for front end use.
- Don't keep your funds on a client on a cloud server unless you trust them.
- The front end shouldn't contact the node to make transactions or handle the private keys, instead, you should use BitcoinJS or Bitcore-lib to create transactions on the front end.

Comment: Hey...Thanks for answering. I expect more helps from you. May I ask an another question please. How to create multiple wallet for multiple users on frond end (I already know to creating multiple account address)....?

Comment: Actually multiple address = = Multiple wallet....???

Comment: Hey... Please respond..

Comment: On the front end? You can hash the username and password to derive the seed, so don't store them (either in the front end or in the back end). Then you can generate addresses/private keys by applying BIP32 transformations, which should be the wallet and should be unique to each user. @salmanfaris

Comment: Thanks for responding @MCCCS .I understand something. But not everything. Actually what is BIP32 transaction. And how generate unique address for each users. I thing that generate address for each users by using RPC call getnewaddress .Is it correct..?

Comment: BIP32, also called a HD wallet, is a way to create multiple addresses for a wallet while being able to generate keys by only storing the master key. You can use getnewaddress to generate a receiving address for Bitcoin Core, but as you'll keep the private keys and funds in Core, make sure to keep the node as secure as you can.

Comment: Actually I don't understand the statement "is a way to create multiple addresses for a wallet while being able to generate keys by only storing the master key". How can possible to implement it. Any practical documents are available to achieve that..??

Comment: @salmanfaris Here's an explanation : https://medium.com/bitcraft/hd-wallets-explained-from-high-level-to-nuts-and-bolts-9a41545f5b0 You can search for "PHP HD wallet" or "PHP BIP32" to find an implementation.